# Mp3 from iPhone library convert to PCM?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mp3, core-audio

I need to read some audio file from the iPhone/iPod library and then pass it to a function to do some detection.
I need to decode from MP3 to PCM in order to pass at the function some chunks of data. My question is: what's the best ay to do this? I know that it can be done by using AVAsset by reading and writing different file or using ExtAudioFileconvert (as seen in apple example). What's the most efficient?